# No puedo agregar y usar objetos en localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objeto, local-storage

Imaginemos que tengo un objeto, digamos, con una serie de **configuraciones** que se deben guardar:

```
var settings = {
    lang: "es",
    animations: true,
    animationsSpeed: 1
}
```

Y queremos **guardar** este objeto en localStorage para que no se pierdan nunca:

```
localStorage.setItem("settings", settings);
```

Pero cuando trato de recuperar su valor más tarde, me devuelve `"undefined"`.

Intentemos ver el valor del `lang` que definimos en el objeto del principio con `alert`:

```
alert(localStorage.settings.lang);
// sale "undefined"
```

Recordando que `localStorage` es un objeto, casi como cualquier otro que algún programador haya hecho jamás, intenté añadir el objeto `settings` **como en cualquier otro objeto**:

```
localStorage.settings = settings;
```

Intenté recuperar el valor de lang con el mismo comando, pero también me devolvió `"undefined"`.

Probé añadir un arreglo a localStorage:

```
localStorage.array = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

e intenté **recuperar** el valor de los tres elementos alertándolos:

```
alert(localStorage.array[0] + localStorage.array[1] + localStorage.array[2]);
```

Esta vez **sí** me **regresó** el resultado.

Por lo que he visto hasta ahora, se **pueden añadir arreglos** pero **no se puede añadir** un **objeto** a `localStorage`, al menos no de la forma convencional.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo **añadir** objetos dentro de `localStorage`?

Gracias de antemano y espero que me puedas ayudar, y probablemente a muchos nuevos programadores también. ¡Ten un lindo día!

Comment: ¿Cómo estás abriendo el archivo HTML? ¿Desde su ubicación en el dispositivo o desde un servidor?

Comment: Estoy abriéndola con el localhost de una app en mi dispositivo.

Answer (score 2):

Hay limitaciones para guardar objetos, pero podría usar formato de cadena. Entonces, la posible solución seria convertirlo:

```
localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings))
```

Si quisiera recuperar el objeto:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings'))
```

Comment: No puedo usar JSON.stringify, me devuelve "The operation is insecure".

Comment: @TechManWalker ¿Está usando firefox, qué versión?

Comment: Se supone que estoy programando con Koder desde iPhone, yo creo que estoy usando Safari

Comment: En realidad estoy utilizando un visor HTML

Comment: ¡Ahmm! Si no estoy mal, Safari no da acceso a archivos locales por defecto, y al intentar guardar el objeto activa su bloqueo de cookies. Entonces tendría que cambiar la configuración en el navegador. O sea, deshabilitar la restricción de archivos locales y cambiar las opciones de cookies: ``Bloquear siempre``

Comment: Traigo eso desactivado y sigue dando error de seguridad, probé usar eval() y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes saber es que localStorage guarda, preferiblemente, strings. En este caso, un json no es más que un string a la que se le da cierto formato para que pueda ser manejable por JavaScript.

Entonces, sabiendo esto, la manera correcta de guardar un objeto JSON dentro de tu localStorage, es haciendo lo siguiente: Primero debe crear su objeto

```
let obj = {
    lang: "en",
    animations: true,
    speed: 1
  }
```

Segundo, debe convertir su objeto en un string con la función [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Esto va a guardar el json en formato string dentro del store de su navegador.

Luego sí puede consultarlo parseando el json, tomándolo desde el localStorage, es decir haciendo uso de la función [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

Ahora sí puede consultarlo y manejaro directamente. Para un ejemplo, [adjunto un snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/gaidyjg/vsjn72qk/)

Comment: No puedo usar JSON.stringify, me devuelve "The operation is insecure".